# Scanner not working properly in recursion call

Tags: recursion, java.util.scanner

So this is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class partOne {
private static Scanner s;
public static void main(String [] args) {
    s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("type: ");


    System.out.println(recursionPartOne(s.next()));


}
public static String recursionPartOne(String str) {
    System.out.print(str + " ");
    if (s.next() == null) {
        return str;
    } else

        return recursionPartOne(s.next());

}
}
```

And this is what it outputs if I give it the following:

```
type: this is a test run
this a run
```

My main goal is to have it output the independent string elements in reverse order using recursion, but right now I can't understand why the s.next() call is skipping every other element and why the `System.out.println(recursionPartOne(s.next()));` is not being called

Thanks for any responses

Answer (score 0):

for your if condition, I think it should be if (str == null) because if you say (s.next() == null), you are looking at the next element and when the if condition fails then you are doing a recursion on yet another next element. Thus, you are skipping elements.

Comment: Good point! Tip: you can use ` for code formatting; that make your answer better readable